# python-docx обновление нумерации

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

Написал функцию которая добавляет нумерованные параграфы. Параграф это ответы на вопросы, сам текст вопроса это заголовок.

```
def add_bold_text(doc_obj, text):
    """
    Функция добавляет жирный текст в документ.
    """
    paragraph = doc_obj.add_paragraph()
    font = paragraph.style.font
    font.name = 'Times New Roman'
    font.size = Pt(14)
    font.bold = False
    paragraph.style = 'List Number'
    run = paragraph.add_run(text)
    font = run.font
    font.name = 'Times New Roman'
    font.size = Pt(14)
    font.bold = True
    paragraph_format = paragraph.paragraph_format
    paragraph_format.alignment = docx.enum.text.WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.JUSTIFY
    paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(0)
    paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(0)
    paragraph_format.line_spacing = 1
```

Идея была чтобы текст выглядел так:

```
  1. Вопрос
1) ответ 1
2) ответ 2
3) ответ 3
  2. Вопрос
1) ответ 1
2) ответ 2
3) ответ 3
```

По итогу получаю что во втором вопросе у ответов продолжается предыдущая нумерация, в документации пытался как обновить стиль нумерации но не нашёл, пожалуйста помогите...